# Rack cookies and ruby strings

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm trying to decode a cookie and the interpreter is escaping backslashes that I need to remain intact.

This works

```
encrypted = %Q{"pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\012J0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0+pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi+fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\0122pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U+cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\012pHa2dzYbKN+2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf+4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\0129KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq+aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\012"}

=> "\"pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0+pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi+fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U+cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\npHa2dzYbKN+2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf+4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq+aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\n\""
```

But when I hit the server with that as a cookie

```
http localhost:9393 Cookie:cookie="\"pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0+pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi+fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U+cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\npHa2dzYbKN+2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf+4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq+aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\n\""
```

and try to retrieve the cookie from my app, it escapes the backslashes and turns + into spaces

```
encrypted_string = request.cookies['cookie']
"\"pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0 pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\\npHa2dzYbKN 2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf 4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\\n\""

string = key.private_decrypt(Base64.decode64(encrypted))
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed
```

What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: "when I hit the server" - does that happen in a terminal? My macos doesn't know command `http`

Comment: Why is your encrypted content also surrounded by quotes, in the data itself?

Comment: Yes, it happens in the console.  I'm using httpie

Comment: The encrypted content %Q(... has quotes, but doesn't need to.  It works with or without them.  I added them to confirm that it still works with them.

Comment: If I were to guess it's because ruby escape sequences are not entirely compatible with terminal, and those backslashes are literal backslashes in the cookie.

Comment: Thanks, I have a service that is hitting it, too (that this request is mocking) and it has the same issue when sending the cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm just using gsub.

```
gsub("\\012","").gsub(" ","+")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code. According to that it perform decoding on cookies you are passing and produce same result.

```
require ‘uri’
```

Say your cookie is:

```
c = “cookie=pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0+pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi+fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U+cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\npHa2dzYbKN+2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf+4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq+aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\n”

URI.decode_www_form(c).to_h
```

Output will be:

```
{"cookie"=>"pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0 pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\npHa2dzYbKN 2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf 4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\n"}
```

See value of cookie key in hash.

```
pgmQKWFl3ZqLWjMR6HISwjzbTSbF3qNj/xABLuR7sTRhG4hhVFDUBhrWLpHyXjOR0I9UB8zpzyOT\nJ0RDv0s9QcJgm5kx0 pPZFmIt/dfv5LH0UIYvEmODnbfqpzjV7uIgpoi fdVJQaHwk1GF5W1F3hg\n2pWmc/aDz8saLG4j5I4U cctEo7uUOOKn2xRszlytNIOylFQramG1UKC6TLFrkXjz24/MEfEPbaO\npHa2dzYbKN 2AOACVrspysnnAeG0W97EvaV9Q3OXdIY/9eElpLzrbgf 4weTG/qRTd7iSjautF0G\n9KMpzusxQxEI6hSrq aYIBHuyUVMBkhGzobPjw==\n
```

You can see `+` is replaced with `space`.

Perform `gsub(‘ ’, ‘+’)` on cookie you received on server end.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I answered that I did a couple days before you looked at it.  Thanks for your time, though.